# How to append dataframe into csv file with columns order changed without iterating over each column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to append new dataframes iteratively to a single CSV file. The problem is dataframes always have same columns names but their order is random.Currently, I am using following code to append new data into csv :

```
with open(name+'.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=f.tell()==0)
```

But this does not work when column order is changed. It keeps appending values in order they come without taking in account the headers. E.g . If column order in the first dataframe id [A,B,C,D] and in the second dataframe, order is [D,C,A,B] the CSV becomes:

```
A,B,C,D
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d
...
d,c,a,b
d,c,a,b
d,c,a,b
...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reindex` function

```
with open(name+'.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.reindex(columns=list('ABCD')).to_csv(f, header=f.tell()==0)
```